# Nuxt.js end to end testing errors after following documentation also using nuxt-auth

Tags: e2e-testing, nuxt.js

Edit: Reduced test case https://github.com/mkstix6/nuxt-e2e-testing-auth-bug

---

I'm following the nuxt.js e2e testing documentation here:

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/development-tools#end-to-end-testing

I am also using the nuxt-auth module (https://auth.nuxtjs.org)

When I follow the documentation and run `npm test` I get errors.

The first few lines are [edit: expanded this a bit]:

```
Entrypoint app = 7e99177222eb06aee534.js f26c11108ae3834e1137.js 3e276f5900ac5332c193.js
[12:04:56 PM] Compiling server
[12:05:01 PM] Compiled server in 5s

Hash: 944950bfae0ad00400a8
Version: webpack 4.20.2
Time: 4945ms
Built at: 10/16/2018 12:05:01 PM
             Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server-bundle.json  995 KiB          [emitted]
Entrypoint app = server-bundle.js
[Vue warn]: Property or method "$auth" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based comp
onents, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Default> at default.vue
       <Root>
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$state' of undefined"

found in

---> <Default> at default.vue
       <Root>
[Vue warn]: Property or method "$auth" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based comp
onents, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Default> at default.vue
       <Root>
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$state' of undefined"

found in

---> <Default> at default.vue
       <Root>
[12:05:02 PM] TypeError: Cannot read property '$state' of undefined
at Proxy.defaultvue_type_template_id_706d1520_render (server-bundle.js:2010:28)
at VueComponent.Vue._render (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:4542:22)
at renderComponentInner (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7532:25)
at renderComponent (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7502:5)
at RenderContext.renderNode (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7418:5)
at RenderContext.next (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2436:14)
at cachedWrite (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2295:9)
at renderElement (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7656:5)
at renderNode (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7420:5)
at renderComponentInner (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7538:3)
at renderComponent (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7502:5)
at RenderContext.renderNode (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7418:5)
at RenderContext.next (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2436:14)
at RenderContext.next (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2449:12)
at cachedWrite (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2295:9)
at renderElement (/PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7646:5)

  2 failed

  Route / exits and render HTML

  /PROJECT_PATH/server-bundle.js:2010

  Rejected promise returned by test. Reason:

  TypeError {
    message: 'Cannot read property \'$state\' of undefined',
  }

  Proxy.defaultvue_type_template_id_706d1520_render (server-bundle.js:2010:28)
  VueComponent.Vue._render (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:4542:22)
  renderComponentInner (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7532:25)
  renderComponent (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7502:5)
  RenderContext.renderNode (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7418:5)
  RenderContext.next (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2436:14)
  cachedWrite (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2295:9)
  renderElement (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7656:5)
  renderNode (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7420:5)
  renderComponentInner (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7538:3)
  renderComponent (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7502:5)
  RenderContext.renderNode (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7418:5)
  RenderContext.next (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2436:14)
  RenderContext.next (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2449:12)
  cachedWrite (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2295:9)
  renderElement (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7646:5)



  Route / exits and render HTML with CSS applied

  /PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32

  Rejected promise returned by test. Reason:

  StatusCodeError {
    error: Buffer @Uint8Array [
```

I have tried the advice in the "Declaring Reactive Properties" page – as hinted to in the error – but I'm quite new to nuxt.js and vue.js; I may have gotten it wrong.

I'm looking for some advice on how to move past these errors.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: its hard to say whats happening without actual code

Comment: Hi @Aldarund. Yes, forgive me. I was hoping  that small chunk of the error might be enough. I have made a reduced test case. Within _/layouts/default.vue_ I have some buttons that I am hiding/showing depending on the user's log-in-state. The code `v-if="$auth.$state.loggedIn"` is enough to cause the error. I could copy more of the (long) error over if that would be useful too. Thank you for replying.

Comment: still no go. $auth will be defined if auth module properly installed and configured.  Is it not working only for test or when u launch too?

Comment: Strangely, running `nuxt` works fine. BUT, if I then run `npm test` in another tab the development server suddenly gets the same errors and won't recover:

Comment: I have expanded the error code above a bit.

Comment: @Aldarund if your patience is still intact I have managed to re-create the problems I'm having. Reduced code here: https://github.com/mkstix6/nuxt-e2e-testing-auth-bug. I hope the readme and the commit messages tell a clear story. Thanks for taking a look at this question either way.